# Using 'moment.js' to add custom date stamp to node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, momentjs

How to use moment.js correctly? I want to save a `created` date to mongoDB using a form? I am currently using:

```js
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

When displaying the date on the blog post, I then use the following to convert it to a more readable format:

```html
<span class="inline-block"><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
```

How to display the current date as `"DD-MM-YYYY @ mm:hh"` when submitting the post?

Comment: What template system are you using?  ejs, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the date value you get from mongodb is a timestamp value:

Then you can use moment.js like this:

```
var timeValueFromMongoDB = 1515089852632;
var result = moment(timeValueFromMongoDB).format('DD-MM-YYYY @ mm:hh');

// Use this output to display wherever you want
04-01-2018 @ 17:01
```

Jsfiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/5208/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Get access to momentjs from your ejs file and then simply do:

```
<%= moment(yourDateVariable).format('DD-MM-YYYY') %>
```

Give format to the date before passing the data to your ejs.

```
yourDateVariable = moment(yourDateVariable).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
return res.render('yourView', {yourDateVariable});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I was very clear when explaining what I was trying to do. I wanted to use moment to convert a date in a .ejs template. The solution was to use:

```js
app.locals.moment = require("moment");
```

in the app.js file and then use:

```js
<span><%= moment(blog.created).fromNow() %></span>
```

Which gave the following rendered result:

[image]